# Hair particle being messed up when joined with a mesh

Tags: mesh, particles, hair

I made a santa hat, i used the hair particle system on some parts of it, but when i try to join all of them together together, the hairs change position, is there any way to fix this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: why do you want to join them? if you want them to move together, what about parenting all to an empy?

Comment: My main goal is not for them to all move together, is there any other way to join them?

Comment: as i wrote, create an empty, parent all items which should move together to that empty, and just move the empty ;)

Comment: Ok thx a lot chris

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add an empty (i took a sphere):

[image]

select all objects and at last, select your empty:

[image]

press CTRL-P -> object

if you now move the empty, all will move with it (and rotate)

[image]

Comment: Alright thanks for your help :)

Comment: If my answer helped you, please click on the checkmark left of my answer. Thank you! You are welcome!